# Meteor instability

Tags: meteor, meteorite, meteor-blaze

I am learning meteor to build an app. I am finding things pretty unstable with Meteor. I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and Meteor 1.0.3

Everything is working fine and I had finished couple of Modules. And Suddenly one day, I get this error:

```
Can't find npm module 'mailcomposer'. Did you forget to call 'Npm.depends' in package.js within the 'email' package?
```

I know that 'mailcomposer' package is not there and installed it and worked well.

And again, projects work fine and again one day suddenly I get this error:

```
Cannot find module 'fibers'.
```

I really want to know what is happening. I have not removed any module nor did I add one. My project was running fine, but later when I opened the system I got the error. Does meteor remove or update modules automatically in the backend? Rather than fixing these errors, I want to know why modules are suddenly being removed.

I am novice in Meteor, apologies if the question is stupid.

Comment: Unusual. Maybe you had updated your npm. Should do `meteor update`

Comment: It is possible that you have cleaned up your NPM module cache. Or some other command deleted it from your system.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when I was deploying an Meteor app on Digital Ocean, for some reason I had to reinstall nodejs and fibers package to make it work again.

Answer (score 0):

Are you switching from 1 node version to another? 
If you are on the server:

1. get meteor's node version `meteor node -v`
2. verify if the server is using the same node version by `node -v`

Let me know...